# getting attr id undefined on click button jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<select class="form-control newclass addvalue input_color" name="CandInv-54" id="sugar_id">
    <option value="">Select Value</option>
    <option selected value="ABSENT">ABSENT</option>
    <option value="1">ADD</option>
</select>

<div id="sssugar_id"> 
    <input id="myInput2" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Fill  Value Or Select Dropdown" style="margin-top: 5px;border-color: green;border-width: medium;" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="mybtn2" class="btn btn-success button_class" style="margin-top: 5px;" onclick="addtest()">ADD</button>
</div>

<script>
    function addtest(){
        var xyz = $('#mybtn2').prev('select').attr('id');
        alert('id ' + xyz);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the `select` is not a sibling of `#mybtn2`, so `prev()` will not return any element. Instead you need to use `parent().prev('#mybtn2')`, like this:

```js
function addtest() {
  var xyz = $('#mybtn2').parent().prev('select').prop('id');
  alert('id ' + xyz);
}
```

Also note that it's much better practice to attach your event handlers using unobtrusive javascript instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes. As you're using jQuery, here's how you can do that:

```js
$('#mybtn2').click(function() {
  var xyz = $(this).parent().prev('select').prop('id');
  alert('id ' + xyz);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control newclass addvalue input_color" name="CandInv-54" id="sugar_id">
  <option value="">Select Value</option>
  <option selected value="ABSENT">ABSENT</option>
  <option value="1">ADD</option>
</select>

<div id="sssugar_id">
  <input id="myInput2" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Fill  Value Or Select Dropdown" style="margin-top: 5px;border-color: green;border-width: medium;" type="text">
  <button type="button" id="mybtn2" class="btn btn-success button_class" style="margin-top: 5px;">ADD</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `parent('div')` for getting selectbox.

```js
function addtest(){
        var xyz = $('#mybtn2').parent('div').prev('select').attr('id');
        alert('id: ' + xyz);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control newclass addvalue input_color" name="CandInv-54" id="sugar_id">
    <option value="">Select Value</option>
    <option selected value="ABSENT">ABSENT</option>
    <option value="1">ADD</option>
</select>

<div id="sssugar_id"> 
    <input id="myInput2" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="Fill  Value Or Select Dropdown" style="margin-top: 5px;border-color: green;border-width: medium;" type="text">
    <button type="button" id="mybtn2" class="btn btn-success button_class" style="margin-top: 5px;" onclick="addtest()">ADD</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanx..very usefullll

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected results ,use below option  which will select parent element of button first and then previous element-select and fetched value of attribute id

```
       $('#mybtn2').parent().prev('select').attr('id');
        alert('id ' + xyz);
     }
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Comment: sure abarisone...corrected :) . I follow this going forward